# Asking user to enter one value from a list and using that value to pull from another list

Tags: python, list, multipleselection

Have beginner Python knowledge and trying to figure out the logic for this.  My experience is in SQL so it has been difficult to get out of that line of thinking.

I would like the user to choose an aircraft from the list and have the program take that corresponding code to pull the price per minute.

I have tried different variations.  You can see the differences in how I set up my lists, trying to see if the problem lies there.

````py
aircraft = {'1':'Fighter Jet','2':'Airliner','3':'Bi-Plane','4':'Aerobatic Plane'}
ppm = {'Fighter Jet':'2.25','2':1.75,'3':'1.00','4':1.50}

def flightcost(time, aircraft):
    y = time
    x = ppm.get(aircraft.code)
    return x * y

time = input('\nHow many minutes would you like to fly?  Please enter 5 - 60 numbers only!   \n')
print('\nHere are the aircraft simulators we have: \n')
for code,airplane in aircraft.items():
    print('{} {}'.format(code, airplane))
aircraft = input('\nType in the numeric code for the plane you prefer? \n')
print('\nHere is your flight cost: ', flightcost)```

Expected results if a user wants to fly for 10 minutes in the Fighter Jet Simulator:

'time = 10 minutes' 
'aircraft = 1:Fighter Jet'
'ppm = 1:2.25'
'flightcost = time (10 minutes) * ppm (2.25)'
'flightcost = 22.50'

Results right now:  '<function flightcost at 0x00845150>'
(The code on the end is always different depending on what I've entered)

Something is happening.  Just not what I am expecting!!!
````

Comment: you are not *calling* the function `flightcost` in `print('\nHere is your flight cost: ', flightcost`): you need to change that to `flightcost()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Below code should work, made 3 edits
aircraft = {'1':'Fighter Jet','2':'Airliner','3':'Bi-Plane','4':'Aerobatic Plane'}
#edit-1, corrected the dictionary ppm, should be using 1 as key and value should be a number
ppm = {'1':2.25,'2':1.75,'3':'1.00','4':1.50}

def flightcost(time, aircraft):
    #edit -2 , as value in ppm is float and we cannot multiply int and float, converted minutes to float. Also it is ppm.get(aircraft) but not ppm.get(aircraft.code)
    y = float(time)
    x = ppm.get(aircraft)
    return x * y

time = input('\nHow many minutes would you like to fly?  Please enter 5 - 60 numbers only!   \n')
print('\nHere are the aircraft simulators we have: \n')
for code,airplane in aircraft.items():
    print('{} {}'.format(code, airplane))
aircraft = input('\nType in the numeric code for the plane you precmdferfer? \n')
#edit-3 - calling flightcost directly doesn't makes any sense, you should pass the parameters required
print('\nHere is your flight cost: ', flightcost(time,aircraft))
```

Answer (score 0):

`flightcost` is a function, and you are trying to print it.
What you actually want to print is the return value of this function, so you should call it and pass it the appropriate arguments: `print('\nHere is your flight cost: ', flightcost(time, aircraft))`.

Your code has some more problems though, I fixed a couple of them:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2                                                                                

aircraft = {1: 'Fighter Jet', 2: 'Airliner', 3: 'Bi-Plane', 4: 'Aerobatic Plane'}
ppm = {1: 2.25, 2: 1.75, 3: 1.00, 4: 1.50}

def flightcost(time, aircraft_code):
    y = time
    x = ppm.get(aircraft_code)
    return x * y

time = input('\nHow many minutes would you like to fly?  Please enter 5 - 60 numbers only!   \n')
print('\nHere are the aircraft simulators we have: \n')
for code, airplane in aircraft.items():
    print('{} {}'.format(code, airplane))

aircraft = input('\nType in the numeric code for the plane you prefer? \n')
print('\nHere is your flight cost: ' + str(flightcost(time, aircraft)))
```

Among the issues I fixed:

- you mixed the aircraft names and id in the keys of the  `ppm` dict.
- you mixed the types of the values in the `ppm` dict, they should all be floats, not strings.
- `aircraft.code` does not exist, you should pass in the aircraft code as a parameter to the `flightcost` function.
- adjusted the call to the final `print` to prevent displaying the output as a tuple.

Comment: Thank you for spending time to fix my code!   I was trying to demonstrate all the different things I had tried in regards to setting up my lists.  Seeing your changes, it makes it much clearer to me on how this should be set up in the future.   Appreciate your help on this one!